# Reading JSON with foreign characters

Tags: c#, json, json.net

I am currently trying to develop a program that will parse a json response and display a few pieces of information to the user.  However, I have reached an issue where the json response contains Japanese characters.  I am currently using Json.NET.  How can I get around this?

Edit: used `Clipboard.SetText(string)` and pasted into notepad and found the following data that caused the exception:

"status":"螟ｩ邱夊ｲ灘潮隱ｪ譌ｩ螳・-蠢・揶邉ｻ蟆冗｢ｺ蟷ｸ蠕ｮ遨榊・譏滓愀諡臥自螳ｶ・御ｸ鮟樣・荳肴枚髱堤噪譁・搨縲・

The exception is `JsonReaderException: After parsing a value an unexpected character was encountered: _. Line 1, position 26125.`  I have pasted the whole response into http://jsonlint.com/ and it detects that those characters are invalid as well.

The method that throws this is `JObject o = JObject.Parse(response);`

Comment: Where is your data coming from?  json objects are by defauly utf-8, and therefore SHOULD allow arabic/chinese/japanese/etc. character sets. What are you trying to DO with the data once you have it?  The above code shows that you ARE getting the correct characters?

Comment: Added in relevant information in the question.

Comment: Could you post the entire JSON you are trying to parse somewhere? By adding `{` and `}` around the above and placing a `"` at the end of the status value, this validated fine. Also, the error indicates that the problematic character is an underscore - there doesn't seem to be one in what you posted.

Comment: Opening the file in a text editor showed that the character at position 26126 is "螟"

Comment: To diagnose this we need to see the whole JSON response. It's probably quite a large amount of text, so use [PasteBin](http://pastebin.com/) or something like that to post the JSON.